# How to backup SonarQube server?

Tags: sonarqube

Today I am backing up MySQL with mysqldump, but I am not sure if I need to save some files from /opt/sonar. Please could you help me with some instructions? 
What do I need to backup in Sonar in addition of MySQL?

Answer (score 5):

I would also backup the configuration files ($SONARQUBE_HOME/conf), plus the list of plugins ($SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins).